# Error in my query getting the maximum value of a varchar

Tags: php, mysql, sql, codeigniter

i am using Codeigniter framework, and i dont know why i got error in my query. When i tried it in query builder navicat, my query runs successfully and returns the maximum number of my field varchar. But when i tried it in my model, it gives me error of :

> ## A Database Error Occurred
>
> Error Number: 1064
>
> You have an error in your SQL syntax;
>   check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for
>   the right syntax to use near '0' at line 1

Here is my query in model :

```
public function checkupID() {
        $query = $this->db->query(' SELECT tbl_check_up.check_up_id FROM tbl_check_up ORDER BY substring_index(tbl_check_up.check_up_id, '-', 1) + 0, 
                    substring_index(tbl_check_up.check_up_id, '-', -1) + 0 DESC LIMIT 1 ');
        return $query->result();
    }
```

Comment: There is an error in your syntax. `substring_index` actually returns a substring and not only the index. So you cannot add 0 or any other integer  directly into it. Please share your exact requirement for the query that you are executing.

Comment: @KeyurPanchal hello sir... i want to make auto increment in query because it is prmary key

Comment: Can you be little more descriptive ?

Comment: @KeyurPanchal hello sir, i just want to make the right side ( 1 - ** ) to be auto increment .. but it is a varchar . thats what i want

Comment: What you are attempting appears to be syntactically valid, but will *eventually* fail spectactularly if you actually design this way, because every query requires a full table scan and there is no way to handle concurrency.  If you want an auto-increment, use an auto-increment.

Comment: Why does `substring_index(tbl_check_up.check_up_id, '-', 1) + 0` seem to be used twice?  You appear to be ordering then ordering again, by exactly the same expression.

Comment: @Michael-sqlbot hello sir. thanks for reply. I only want is to get the highest value of my varchar.. in my post i have 1-10. thats what i want then i go to my controller and increment the value.

Comment: @KeyurPanchal helloo sir. i just want to return the highest value in my column that is varchar. in my post i want to return the 1-10

Comment: Please add more detail about what you are trying to do? That detail might help other to help you. @JcJohn

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps you are looking for the length of the first substring (prior to a dash) as the way to order?

```
SELECT tbl_check_up.check_up_id 
FROM tbl_check_up 
ORDER BY
  length(substring_index(tbl_check_up.check_up_id, '-', 1)) 
LIMIT 1
;
```

However I am not sure what was intended for the second part of the order by.

+EDIT, correction.
-1 is valid as third parameter to substring_index

Comment: Using -1 **is** valid as the third argument to `SUBSTRING_INDEX()`:  [*"If* count *is negative, everything to the right of the final delimiter (counting from the right) is returned."*](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/string-functions.html#function_substring-index)

Comment: Oh. Thanks. Good to know.

Comment: @Used_By_Already thanks for your reply. why this returns 1-9? sir.. please check it.. i need the 1-10

Comment: @Used_By_Already all i want is to get the highest value of the right side.. like for example in my post. i want to get 1-10

Comment: Trying to describe technical needs through words does not work, or referencing code snippets that do not work isn't helpful either. DATA, supply SAMPLE DATA and EXPECTED RESULT. Put this in the question, do not try to do this in a comment as it will require formatting control.

Comment: just so I am clear: I am asking that you provide an EXAMPLE we can follow what your want to achieve. **nb** If this function is intended to create a unique new value for the "next row" in a table then this is not going to scale at all well.